# Unable to test python method since mock always returns an object regardless of property existence

Tags: python, unit-testing

Here's a contrived python class with one method followed by one test for that method.
Now, I understand *why* the test is failing. It's because Mock returns a mock object regardless of what property you try to access. However, this makes me unsure how to properly test my unit of code without doing something hacky like setting the properties `a`,`b`, and `c` explicitly to `None`. That seems wrong. In other languages like Javascript, mock objects return null or undefined when accessing properties that don't exist, and even when you try to access an undefined property of an object in Python you get an Attribute error, so I am having a hard understanding why python Mock was implemented with such behavior. I know one of the benefits is that Mock objects record all calls made on the mock, but I would have expected the mock to throw an error much like any object when trying to access a property which doesn't exist.

I'm very new to python (though I've been programming for 7+ years), so I'm probably just approaching this wrong or missing some key detail.

**TLDR**: I want the below test to pass, but it fails since the `SomeClass` object instance's `a` attribute never gets set.

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock

class SomeClass():
    def set_defaults_if_not_set(self, value: object):
        if not value.a:
            print("setting default a!")
            value.a = "default a"

        if not value.b:
            print("setting default b!")
            value.b = "default b"

        if not value.c:
            print("setting default c!")
            value.c = "default c"
        
        print("returning value!")
        return value


class TestSomeClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_set_defaults_if_not_set(self):
        instance = SomeClass()
        mock_value = Mock()

        instance.set_defaults_if_not_set(mock_value)
        self.assertEqual(mock_value.a, "default a") 

unittest.main()
```

Comment: Python raises an exception if an attribute does not exist.  It is quite normal to initialize all the properties of an object to None.  The code you have is destined to fail anyway; after `value = value.a = "default a"`, `value` will be a string, and not an object.  I'm not sure what you were trying to do there.

Comment: @TimRoberts you're correct, that was a copy/pasta error. thanks for noting, i've corrected the code in the question!

Comment: @TimRoberts What I'm trying to accomplish: existing tests in the file I'm working on already use this format, so I was trying to build on it but was confused why others had explicitly set properties to None to get the test to pass. (It makes sense of course, but the pattern didn't seem right). If I'm understanding correctly from your response, this is just a pythonic way of doing things. I would've thought a better pattern would be conditionals such as `if not hasattr(value, "a"): value.a = "default a"`, but that wouldn't work in this case either since mocks always return an value for any key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `Mock` object with a spec which will then allow only the attributes which are there in the spec and nothing else.

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> m = mock.Mock(["a", "b", "c"])
>>> m.a.return_value = 10
>>> m.a()
10
>>> m.b
<Mock name='mock.b' id='140456403476320'>
>>> m.x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 590, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'x'
>>>
```